# React Native Promises - They don't wait

Tags: react-native

I'm struggling again with promises, I don't understand or I'm expecting something else...

Really simple:

```
  const getImageRatio = () => {
    let res = Image.getSize(url, (w, h) => {
      console.log('width',w);
      return w / h;
    });
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(res));
  };
```

I get correctly `width`

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const fetcher = await getImageRatio();
      console.log('fetcher', fetcher);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

but `fetcher is undefined`

I understood that the `useEffect async` is suppose to wait for the `res`
or not?
Where I'm mistaking?

codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-problem-k2cgz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are always `resolve`ing your promise even if it gets `reject`ed. You have to `resolve` it when it actually resolves after getting `width` & `height` from the `Image.getSize` function.

Try replacing your `getImageRatio` function with the following:

```js
const getImageRatio = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Image.getSize(
      url,
      (width, height) => {
        resolve({ width, height });
      },
      (error) => reject(error)
    );
  });
};
```